# Cash Dividend implies skewed (negative) vol smile?

Tags: black-scholes, volatility-smile, dividends

Say we have a stock $S_t$ which pays a cash dividend at $T_D$ of amount $div$. Let us assume rates $r=0$, for simplicity. Then the forward is $F_{T_D} = S_0 - div$, and we can compute the continuous dividend yield of $q_{T_D} = -\log(F_{T_D}/S_0)/T_D$.

If $BS(T,K,q,\sigma)$ is the Black-Scholes call option price and $\sigma(T,K)$ the implied vol for expiry $T$ and strike $K$, then
\begin{align}
  BS(T_D^+, K, q=q_{T_D}, \sigma(T_D^+,K))
  &= \mathbb{E}[(S_{T_D^+} - K)^+]\\\\
  &= \mathbb{E}[(S_{T_D^-} - div - K)^+]\\\\
  &= BS(T_D^-, K+div, q=0, \sigma(T_D^-,K+div))\\\\
\end{align}
This means, if we know $\sigma(T_D^+,K)$, then we can use the above to imply $\sigma(T_D^-,K+div)$. Assuming our vol surface is smooth & does not jump, we can drop superscripts $^+$ and $^-$. So applying this argument successively, we can use $\sigma(T_D,K+div)$ to obtain $\sigma(T_D,K+2div)$, and then $\sigma(T_D,K+3div)$, and so on. And each $\sigma$ has to be strictly smaller than the previous one, as each strike is strictly larger than the previous one (if $div>0$). Which implies a negative vol smile.

So if $div > 0$, then the entire smile at $T_D$ is exactly implied by the above procedure. And the smile must be negative. **Is this correct?**

Because if this is indeed the case, then a flat vol surface would be impossible (as it would violate the above)?

---

I put this to a test using a small Python scripts:

```python
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.optimize import root
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def black_scholes_call_price(S, K, T, r, q, vol):
    d1 = (np.log(S/K) + (r - q + vol**2/2)*T) / (vol * np.sqrt(T))
    d2 = d1 - vol * np.sqrt(T)
    return np.exp(-q*T) * S * norm.cdf(d1) - np.exp(-r*T) * K * norm.cdf(d2)

def black_scholes_call_implied_vol(S, K, T, r, q, price):
    price_diff = lambda vol: black_scholes_call_price(S, K, T, r, q, vol) - price
    results    = root(price_diff, x0=0.2)
    return results.x[0] if results.success else float('nan')

S0  = 100
div = 5
T   = 1.0  # same as T_D
FT  = S0 - div
qT  = -np.log(FT/S0)/T

K   = 100
vol = 0.30

strikes = [K]
vols    = [vol]

for i in range(50):
    npv = black_scholes_call_price(S0, K, T, r=0, q=qT, vol=vol)
    K   = K + div
    vol = black_scholes_call_implied_vol(S0, K, T, r=0, q=0, price=npv)
    strikes.append(K)
    vols.append(vol)

plt.plot(strikes, vols, '.-')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

which indeed gives a negative smile:

[image: vol smile]